# Initializes a class with n-nested tuples

Tags: python, class, attributes

In python is there a way to initialize a class with n-nested tuples? with x being 0 to n and y being an empty list.

What I mean is:

Suppose you have a class such as:

```
class NestedTuples:
    def __init__(self, tuple):
        self.tuple = ?
```

so if you were to do something like:

```
t = NestedTuples(4)
```

it will create:

```
((0, []), (1, []), (2, []), (3, []))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works*:

```
class NestedTuples:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.tuple = tuple((x, []) for x in range(num))
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> class NestedTuples:
...     def __init__(self, num):
...         self.tuple = tuple((x, []) for x in range(num))
...
>>> t = NestedTuples(4)
>>> t.tuple
((0, []), (1, []), (2, []), (3, []))
>>>
```

Lastly, here is a reference on [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

---

*Note: I had to rename the `tuple` parameter of `NestedTuples.__init__`.  You should never create a variable that has the same name as one of the built-ins.  Doing so will overshadow it.

Comment: Thank you :) didn't realize it would be this easy.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code:

```
param = 4
nestedTuple = tuple([(i,[]) for i in range(param)])
print nestedTuple
```

**Output:**

```
((0, []), (1, []), (2, []), (3, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [74]: class NestedTuples:
    ...:     def __init__(self, n):
    ...:         self.tuple = tuple((i, []) for i in range(n))
    ...:         

In [75]: t = NestedTuples(4)

In [76]: t.tuple
Out[76]: ((0, []), (1, []), (2, []), (3, []))
```